# How to avoid repeating HTML elements in livewire component in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

**Context:**

- `<livewire:item-detail/>` Component consist of one button element and a Bootstrap modal.
- Component `<livewire:item-detail/>` is used in blade for a table in each row using loop.
- When i click that button, the modal popup and show information of item of the row in the table.

| Items | Action |
| --- | --- |
| Item 1 | <kbd>More Details</kbd> <-button from component |
| Item 2 | <kbd>More Details</kbd> <-button from component |

**Problem:**

- While looping the component `<livewire:item-detail/>` . Modal element also repeating.

How can i make that into one modal for all button rendered in table. while keeping livewire component single for each row ?

Note : only `<livewire:item-detail/>` component is from livewire. rest of the code is written in normal blade file

Comment: You can put the modal in a separate livewire component and add it to the blade once. then use the Livewire Events for their commiunication.

Comment: @Amirsadjad but 'emitUp' is only working for the first row, when i emit event from child to parent of any row, first row's parent is getting the event.

Comment: 'emmitUp' is for a child to trigger an event on the parent component. You don't need to define the modal as a child  for the main component. Just define them separately and use 'emmit' or js events.